# Check if a Powershell script has frozen using a separate script

Tags: powershell, jenkins, automated-tests, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

So I'm preforming some automated testing using powershell in jenkins. I'm testing a web application where I must fill out forms, retrieve values, etc.

It is all fine but the web app contains some pop up messages that appear every now and then, which causes the main script to freeze until they are manually closed in the application. Below is a link to a stack overflow thread with a similar problem.

[Powershell Website Automation: Javascript Popup Box Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303636/powershell-website-automation-javascript-popup-box-freeze)

I followed the advice of the first answer. I created a separate powershell script that is executing constantly and can tell if there is a pop up window present (as they have their own process ids, so if there is more then one iexplore process id present it must be a popup) and then uses sendkeys to close it.

Main Script example:

```
#start application
start C:\Users\Webapp

#start the monitor script
Start-Process Powershell.exe -Argumentlist "-file C:\Users\Monitor.ps1"

#Get app as object
$app = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $ClientSelectPage = $app.Windows() | where {$_.LocationURL -like     "http:webapp.aspx"}

#Input value to cause popup message
 $MemNumberInput = $ClientSelectPage.Document.getElementByID("MemNum")
            $MemNumberInput.Select()
            $MemNumberInput.value = "22" 
            $FindBtn.click()
```

It is at this point my script will freeze (as pop up window appears to tell me info abotu the client I've inserted) If this popup can be seen as a process, the monitor code will close it.

Example of monitor

```
      $i = 0

     while($i -eq 0)
     {

#Check what process are currently running under the webapps name
     $Mainprocid = Get-Process | where {$_.mainWindowTitle -like "*webapp*" } | select -expand id
      $Mainprocid.COUNT

     $integer = [int]$Mainprocid 

#If there is only one process, no action
         if( $Mainprocid.count -eq 1)
         {
            echo "no popup"

         }
          else
          {   
                if($integer -eq '0') 
                {
              #If there are no processes close the script
               $i = 1
               echo "close process"

                }
                else
#If there are two processes one must be a pop, send 'enter' to the app
                {

            echo "POP UP!"   
        $title = Get-Process |where {$_.mainWindowTItle -like "*webapp*"} 
       #Code to sendkeys 'ENTER' to the application to close the popup follows here
                   }
          }   
      }
```

However, for whatever reason, some pop ups cannot be found as processes and the monitor script is useless with them. These are few and far between, so I figured the best way was for the monitor script to check and see if the main script has frozen for a certain amount of time. If so, it can use the sendkeys method it does for the other popups.

Is there a way for me to check and see if the main script has frozen, from the monitor script? I understand I could pass a parameter from the main script every now and then, to let the monitor script know it is still active, but this seems like a messy way of doing it, and an alternative method would be preferable.

Both scripts are saved as .ps1 files.

Comment: Where is the 'monitor' script you wrote?  Do you have any idea where the 'freeze' is taking place?  Can you provide a [mcve] of any kind?

Comment: Hi, relative code added to the question, thanks.